# multiprocessing slower than loop

Tags: python, csv, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to write huge data to a csv file. When I try normal method it writes 50 data in 1 second but with multiprocessing it's down to 5 data in 1 second.
And I also added this code `sys.setrecursionlimit(25000)`. Because without it's giving error.

I can feel I'm not doing right. What is the right way?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import csv
import cchardet
from multiprocessing import Pool
import sys
import time

sys.setrecursionlimit(25000)

csvfileWrite=open("comments.csv", 'a+', newline='',encoding='utf-8') #declared as a global variable
writer = csv.writer(csvfileWrite, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', 
quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) #declared as a global variable


def kacYildiz(div): #This function returns a number 0 to 5. Not important.
    yildizSayisi=0
    yildizYeri=div.find("div",attrs={"class":"RatingPointer-module-1OKF3"})
    yildizlar=yildizYeri.find_all("svg")
    
    for yildiz in yildizlar:
        sonuc=yildiz.find("path").get("fill")
        if(sonuc=="#f28b00"):
            yildizSayisi+=1

    return yildizSayisi

def takeText(div):
    comment=div.find("span",attrs={"itemprop":"description"}).text
    return comment


def yorumSayfaSayisi(row): # This function returns a number that how many 
    pages in the sites comment section. Not important.
    yorumKismi="-yorumlari?"
    adres=row[0]+yorumKismi

    r = requests_session.get(adres)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    
    sayfaS=soup.find("ul",attrs={"class":"PaginationBar-module-3qhrm"})
        
    sayi=sayfaS.find_all("li")[-1].text
    return sayi



def writeToCsv(comments): #writing commets to csv file.
    global csvfileWrite
    global writer
   
    textToWrite = takeText(comments)
                    
    writer.writerow([kacYildiz(comments),textToWrite]) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pageNumber=1
    requests_session = requests.Session()
    comments=list()
    
    csvfile=open('adresler.csv',newline='')
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')

          
    for row in reader:
        rowNumber=yorumSayfaSayisi(row)
            
        for i in range(1,int(rowNumber)):
            comments.clear()
            commetAdress="-yorumlari?sayfa={}".format(i)               
            adress=row[0]+commetAdress                  
            r = requests_session.get(adress)                
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml") 
            page=soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"ReviewCard-module- 
            3Y36S"})  

            for comment in page:
                comments.append(comment)

            p = Pool(10)
            start = time.process_time()   
            p.map(writeToCsv, comments) 
                
            p.terminate()
            p.join()
```

Comment: Please use proper English names for your variables/objects if you expect people to understand what the code does. Take note that no matter what the code is intended to do, ``global`` + ``multiprocessing`` generally does *not* do what you think it does. Globals are not shared across processes, but copied.

Comment: So.. are all threads writing to the same file? I would guess this means that they'll have to take turns

Comment: @lucidbrot the code is using seperate *processes*, but yes, I think that is what the code is doing, which would definitely take longer than just processing it serially.

Comment: You must provide a [mcve]. That doesn't mean the whole code. But it must be something that actually runs.

Comment: It is not really clear what your code is doing, since key parts are missing – e.g. is ``------main-----`` a function, or inside a ``__main__`` guard, or top-level? Similarly, ``sys.setrecursionlimit(25000)`` is unneeded for this code, since there is no recursion – which part does need the higher limit? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (which is something different than the full code). See the [ask] page how to best help us help you.

Comment: @lucidbrot yes same file. I'm gonna edit the code. Sorry i'm actually new in here.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i put -----main---- to indicate after that codes in main ,not in a function.And after i remove sys.setrecursionlimit(25000) error says ''maximum recursion depth exceeded''

Comment: Again, please take a look at the [mcve] help page. *Help us help you* and provide code *for your actual problem*, not the entire application. Remember that people on [so] are volunteers with limited time. Please also take the time to *shortly* outline what you are trying to do – ``multiprocessing`` is most useful for CPU bound tasks (computation), yet it looks like your problem is I/O bound (network and disk). In specific, if write speed is your issue, note that consumer grade filesystems and hardware generally perform better for ordered, sequential writes instead of random, concurrent writes.

Answer (score 0):

once try this approach using ThreadPool

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def csvYaz(yorumlar):
    global csvfileYaz
    global yazici
    yazi = yorumAl(yorumlar)
    yazici.writerow([kacYildiz(yorumlar),yazi])

# ------main-----
for yorum in yorumSayfasi:
    yorumlar.append(yorum)

threads = ThreadPool(10).map(csvYaz, yorumlar)
for zz in threads:
    print(zz)
```

Comment: Writing speed has not changed.

Comment: try to increase the pools, like 100 or 200

Comment: Most consumer grade HDD/SSD hardware will *not* see a performance increase when using multiple writers, which implies small, random, interleaved writes. Common HDDs can service roughly 2-4 concurrent threads for the same *total* performance as one single thread, which implies large, ordered writes. Using 100 to 200 writer threads is way too much for consumer grade hardware, and will also incur a hefty cost for overhead from Python's GIL.